# Cut and paste in the same position issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have problem when I slice my shape here and put it in the same place here is like a small line between cut object and original object.

1. So I have created a shape.
2. I have cut it with unchecked anti aliasing checkmark
3. I pasted it back to the position.

Here is [video](http://screencast.com/t/cPPVHiNZVR) how it looks like. Thank for help!

Answer (score 1):

#### There is no issue

When using a zoom level, other than 100%, Photoshop softens the edges for a nicer view. The actual layer data is hard edged as expected, the view is softened, only.

Answer (score 0):

**In photoshop you never want to use cut and paste**
Right photoshop work would be:
1. Select the area
2. Go to the layers window, duplicate the layer with cmd/ctrl J. You'll get a new layer with only the selected part.
3.Reselect the same layer (on the layers window hold cms/ctrl)
4. Inverse the selection (Select>inverse)
5. Go to the original layer and create a mask
I know it sounds complicated compared to 2 simple keyboard shortcuts but when you start doing more complicated things you will understand how important it is to work properly and everything I wrote down will be as simple and fast for you as cms+z>cmd>v

Comment: thank you for answer, here still the same issue with scale. On the step 5 I selected first my lever with inverted selection and make cmd j to duplicated it.

Comment: It does not matter which workflow you choose, the zoom level anti aliasing will always have this side effect.

Comment: Why would it be bad to use cut and paste?